# Intuition behind "stochastic orthogonality"

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Whilst doing an exercise on the Brownian Motion on a sphere I came across this identity:
$$
\langle Z\times B,Z\times B\rangle = 2|Z|^2dt
$$
where $\times$ denotes the cross product and $Z$ is a diffusion process and $B$ a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does anyone have intuition for that?

Thank you!

Comment: I want to say it has something to do with the quadratic variance of Brownian motion being non-zero, but let me think about it more.

Comment: The brackets denote an inner product? I don't fully understand the notation.

Comment: yes, it does indeed